# Contract supplied an invalid parameter

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-client, transactions, testnet, parameter

I have a little problem because my mint does not pass because of invalid parameters, I don't quite understand why..., in the entrypoint call I deliberately did not put the token_id parameter because otherwise the transaction does not even appear on the explorer, by not putting it, the transaction appears in the explorer but it fails.

```
 // Sets amount and fee for the transaction.
    BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal("0"); // To call a contract, you send 0 tez.
    BigDecimal fee = new BigDecimal("0.1"); // Minimum fee to call contracts.
    System.out.println("Calling the contract (inserting customer 1, please wait a minute)...");
    
    // Calls the contract.
    JSONObject jsonObject = wallet.callContractEntryPoint("tz1aKq1jeX1QCSGayt4MNrynsynrHTeSfmvA", "KT1XQy1ZcXaqzT2eEgwZDU3wTGK5xNWzMcRt", amount, fee, "", "", "mint",
    new String[]{"tz1aKq1jeX1QCSGayt4MNrynsynrHTeSfmvA", "50", "ORN"}, false, Global.GENERIC_STANDARD);
    
    // Waits for the transaction to be included, so that we can call the contract once more.
    String opHash = (String) jsonObject.get("result");
    Boolean opHashIncluded = wallet.waitForResult(opHash, 8);
    System.out.println(opHashIncluded + " " + opHash);
```

and the output on the explorer:

[image]

[image]

help me please :)

Answer (score 0):

It is required that you provide all parameters.

You have minted successfully twice.

Have a look at: https://better-call.dev/hangzhou2net/KT1XQy1ZcXaqzT2eEgwZDU3wTGK5xNWzMcRt/operations

Comment: the two times it worked was when i interacted in cli but i can't interact with my java code :(

Comment: in my code, when I enter the parameters address, amount, symbol, id it returns me this: java.lang.Exception: Wrong number of parameters to contract entrypoint. But when I put the parameters address, amount, symbol the transaction is done but it fails and on the explorer you can see that in the json the parameters are null...

Comment: I never tried the Java SDK, it may be a bug. Try to use the michelson JSON directly https://pastebin.com/raw/i8d7aUGE .